# Spring Security : HttpSecurity vs WebSecurity

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm unable to differentiate between the following HttpSecurity and WebSecurity methods.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
    webSecurity
    .ignoring()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/register");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/register").permitAll();
}
```

**ignoring()** and **permitAll()** makes the URLs as open URL, thus giving access to un-authenticated users also.
But when to use which method ?

**HttpSecurity.authenticated()** method gives access to all authenticated users, irrespective of role.

But, what is the difference between WebSecurity. ignoring() and HttpSecurity.permitAll() ?

Comment: Seems like you have the identified the difference. What’s the question exactly?

Comment: i have update the body. 
what is the difference between WebSecurity. ignoring() and HttpSecurity.permitAll() ?

Comment: One bypasses spring security entirely. The other allows for anonymous access to the specified location.

Comment: But the end result looks same. So, when to use which method ?

Comment: Not at all. One bypasses spring security the other allows for anonymous access. If you consider them to be the same, I guess you read up on the differences. Security, especially _permitting_ access is not something to be trifled with - read, learn, understand!

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? Correct me if i'm wrong, what i could understand is WebSecurity.ignoring() bypasses spring security, that is equivalent to an open API.
But, HttpSecurity.permitAll() allows access to the url without any authentication.
With this scenario, i'm concluding both methods are equivalent in a way, that they allow un-authenticated users to access the API.

Comment: Only thing i'm trying to understand is which method to use when ?

Comment: HttpSecurity.permitAll() allows access to the url without any authentication. But it doesn’t mean Spring Security doesn’t do anything, right?   For example, a login page, you want everyone to access it, and you will use permit all, but you will definitely ignore it from the whole Spring security.

Comment: Yes. But what operations Spring security perform on the HTTP request where URL can be accessed by anyone ?
I understand it passes through the spring servlet filters, but once we ignore the url, is there any additional checks the spring security takes.